# The union of line $\bf{L}$ and plane $\bf{P}$ is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$, right?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume a vector space $\mathbb{R^3}$, in which a plane $\bf{P}$ and a line $\bf{L}$ which are passing through the origin vector $\bf{Z^3}$. It can be easily seen that $\bf{P}$ and $\bf{L}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^3}$. I was watching the MIT videos of linear algebra by Gilbert Strang and got a doubt here.

The union of $\bf{L}$ and $\bf{P}$ is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$, right? Because $\bf{P \bigcup L}$ is $\bf P$ itself, right?

Comment: Is it closed under addition? Check in a picture.

Comment: Addition of any 2 vectors would lie in the Plane P itself , right?

Comment: What about adding one vector from the plane that is not on the line, and one point on the line?

Comment: That vector will not be in line L but in plane P, right?

Comment: $\bf{P \bigcup L} = \bf{P}$ only if $\bf{L}$ lies in $\bf{P}$, in which case you are correct.

Comment: Why would $P\cup L$ be equal to $P$? Is it an assumption?

Comment: Just imagine a line perpendicular to a plane, then their union is not the plane.

Comment: OK now I got it. My mistake, should I delete the question or update it.

Comment: In general, the union of two subspace is a vector subspace iff one of the subspace is included in the other.

Comment: @dexterdev Do not delete it, if it is not a duplicate -- someone else might find it useful. You can accept/vote the answers. If you want, updating your question based on the answers/comments is a good habit -- but you should not modify it in such way, that the answers already posted would not make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{P \bigcup L}$ is not necessarily a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

As seen in the comments, the statement $\bf{P \bigcup L}$ is $\bf P$ only when both plane 
$\bf P$ and line $\bf L$ coincides. Else where "closed under addition" condition doesn't hold which means addition of 2 vectors in $\bf{P \bigcup L}$ can result in a vector that is outside of $\bf{P \bigcup L}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it into a subspace by doing the direct sum 
$$
P \oplus L :=\left\{p+l , p \in P , l \in L\right\}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, Can some one explain this?